# Stopping deck.gl's viewstate transition with transitionInterruption

Tags: vue.js, deck.gl

I'm using vue in combination with deck.gl, during a view state transition it keeps playing until the transition has finished even when interrupted.

Init deck:

```
this.deck = new Deck({
  canvas: 'deck-canvas',
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',
  initialViewState: this.initialViewState,
  controller: true,
  onViewStateChange: ({ viewState }) => {
    this.map.jumpTo({
      center: [viewState.longitude, viewState.latitude],
      zoom: viewState.zoom,
      bearing: viewState.bearing,
      pitch: viewState.pitch,
    });
  },
});
```

Creating a new view transition:

```
this.deck.setProps({
  viewState: {
    ...predefinedCameraPosition,
    transitionInterpolator: new FlyToInterpolator(),
    transitionDuration: 2000,
    transitionInterruption: this.deck._onViewStateChange.bind(this)
  }
})
```

I expect the transition to stop when the user interrupts it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out another function was manipulating deck.gl's layer state. Updating the viewState at the same time fixed this.

```
this.deck.setProps({
  layers: [...this.deckLayers],
  viewState: this.deck.viewState
});
```